# how to add a constant column to a dataframe without rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a column with a constant value to a dataframe that does not have any rows. It appears this isn't as easy as it would be if the rows were populated. How would one accomplish this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c'])
df['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Should yield

```
 a   b   c   foo
0 NaN NaN NaN bar
```

instead it yields

```
  a   b   c
```

Comment: it will return an empty dataframe; ``Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, foo]
Index: []
``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) specifying the row index and column label, as follows:

```
df.loc[0, 'foo'] = 'bar'
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

     a    b    c  foo
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  bar
```

You can also use:

```
df['foo'] = ['bar']
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

     a    b    c  foo
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  bar
```

If you have a bunch of a mix of empty and non-empty dataframes and you want to assign new column to it, you can try the following code:

```
df['foo'] = ['bar'] * (df.shape[0] if df.shape[0] else 1)
```

This will assign the constant with the same length (number of rows) for  non-empty dataframes and will also assign one new row for empty dataframe with the constant value for the column.

Comment: Nice! However, if I were running this on a bunch of dataframes and some have more than one row I want to fill, is there any way more efficient than

`if len(df) == 0:

    df.loc[0,'foo']='bar'

else:
   df['foo'] = 'bar'`

Comment: @ACan  That's an interesting question!  I think it depends on whether the bunch of dataframes have any common pattern which you can ride on to derive a short cut or better way for it.  I don't have any sure shot and universal answer for this yet.

Comment: @ACan  The code you proposed is a feasible way for it.  At least you won't get empty dataframe without warning but found it afterwards unexpectedly.

Comment: @ACan  See my edit above, you can use a more compact code `df['foo'] = ['bar'] * (df.shape[0] if df.shape[0] else 1)` for your bunch of dataframes.